# Draw shape on a 3d model

Tags: ios, 3d, cocos3d

I want to draw a triangle shape over a 3d head model.

I have tried with drawing the triangle on the texture and applied it over the 3d model. But it will not help completely. When texture render on the 3d model, it get stretch.

```
CC3MeshNode *tnode = [avatar getMeshNodeNamed:@"polySurface1-submesh0"];
tnode.material.isOpaque=YES; //set alpha value 

tnode.material.sourceBlend=GL_SRC_ALPHA;
tnode.material.destinationBlend=GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA;

CC3Texture *texture = nil;
texture = [[CC3Texture alloc] initFromFile:@"hairbuilder.png"]; //create texture image that added with the shape. 

[tnode.material addTexture:texture];

[texture release];
```

Is there any way to draw shape directly over the 3d model

[image]

Comment: Pleas describe your issue a bit better. What is the result you are expecting and what is the result you are getting. You might be looking for a billboard matrix.

Comment: As Matic indicates, please provide more about what you are trying to accomplish. Do you want to add a triangular mesh node to the model (like as if the character was putting on a hat), or do you want to draw a triangle around the head in 2D, as if someone had drawn a triangle on the head of the character on the screen?

Comment: Sorry for lack of explanation. The real need is user has to draw a triangle on the head of the character.

Comment: Do you mean you want the triangle to follow the contour of the head, or do you mean just a 2D triangular overlay, like the image you have on the right above? Following the contour will necessitate tracking the locations of the vertices in the head mesh. And when you say that the user "draws" the triangle, how is this done? Does the user drag a virtual "brush" (or finger) across part of the head to paint the area, or do they touch one place and a triangle of a fixed size appears there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should look at [Projective Texture Mapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_texture_mapping), which is often used to render decals, like bullet holes on objects. With this technique you'll be able to draw your triangle with selected size and orientation.

Here're few other links that can help you:

http://www.ozone3d.net/tutorials/glsl_texturing_p08.php

http://blog.wolfire.com/2009/06/how-to-project-decals/

http://broniac.blogspot.com/2011/06/deferred-decals.html